# PHP - Short-Hand If Syntax Error

Tags: php, shorthand-if

so I originally have this code, but it gives a `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING`:

```
.($page > 1 ? "<li><a href='browse.php?p=".$page-1."'></a></li>" : "")
```

I checked again and again for: `'"'"`, but I got none.

**I changed `.$page-1.` to `.($page-1).`, but still nothing**

Then it worked by adding a new variable:

```
$pagem1 = $page-1;
...
.($page > 1 ? "<li><a href='browse.php?p=$pagem1'></a></li>" : "")
```

I solved my problem but I wonder, **how can you achieve a 1-lined code without adding a new variable**?

### Full Code:

```
echo "<div class='pagination' style='font-size:18px; display:block;'>
        <span>Page $page of $totalpages</span>
        <ul class='pull-right'>
            ".($page > 2 ? "<li><a href=''>First</a></li>" : "")
            .($page > 2 ? "<li class='page-dots'><span>...</span></li>" : "")
            .($page > 1 ? "<li><a href='browse.php?p=".$page-1."'><i class='fa fa-long-arrow-left'></i></a></li>" : "") //First error on this line
            .($page == 1 ? "<li><a class='disabled'>1</a></li>" : ($page != $totalpages ? "<li><a href='browse.php?p=".$page-1."'>".$page-1."</a></li>" : "<li><a href='browse.php?p=".$page-2."'>".$page-2."</a></li>"))
            .($page != 1 && $page != $totalpages ? "<li><a class='disabled'>$page</a></li>" : ($page == 1 ? "<li><a href='browse.php?p=".$page+1."'>".$page+1."</a></li>" : "<li><a href='browse.php?p=".$page-1."'>".$page-1."</a></li>"))
            .($page == $totalpages ? "<li><a class='disabled'>1</a></li>" : ($page != 1 ? "<li><a href='browse.php?p=".$page+1."'>".$page+1."</a></li>" : "<li><a href='browse.php?p=".$page+2."'>".$page+2."</a></li>"))
            .($page < $totalpages - 2 ? "<li class='page-dots'><span>...</span></li>" : "")
            .($page < $totalpages - 2 ? "<li><a href='browse.php?p=".$totalpages."'>Last</a></li>" : "")
            .($page < $totalpages - 1 ? "<li><a href='browse.php?p=".$page+1."'><i class='fa fa-long-arrow-right'></i></a></li>" : "")."
        </ul>
    </div>
";
```

*This code is reconstructed, but this original one had no quotes problems*

Comment: Please post the code that includes this concatenation. There's more to this than just partial line you posted. Without other context, that ternary is not syntactically invalid ,and is correctly `()` enclosed.

Comment: post your full code.. suppose outer quote(") is misplaced... look this is well https://eval.in/184312

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parentheses? `".($page-1)."`

Otherwise, you have

- String
- Concatenate with
- `$page`
- Minus
- `1.`
- String??? Error!

Comment: i did! but my server keeps saying i got the error on that line

Answer (score 0):

Use `($page - 1)` instead of `$page - 1;`

```
$page = 3; $totalpages = 5; // let $page = 3 and $totalpages  = 5
echo "<div class='pagination' style='font-size:18px; display:block;'>
    <span>Page $page of $totalpages</span>
    <ul class='pull-right'>
        ".($page > 2 ? "<li><a href=''>First</a></li>" : "")
.($page > 2 ? "<li class='page-dots'><span>...</span></li>" : "")
.($page > 1 ? "<li><a href='browse.php?p=".($page-1)."'><i class='fa fa-long-arrow-left'></i></a></li>" : "") //First error on this line
        .($page == 1 ? "<li><a class='disabled'>1</a></li>" : ($page != $totalpages ? "<li><a href='browse.php?p=".($page-1)."'>".($page-1)."</a></li>" : "<li><a href='browse.php?p=".($page-2)."'>".($page-2)."</a></li>"))
        .($page != 1 && $page != $totalpages ? "<li><a class='disabled'>$page</a></li>" : ($page == 1 ? "<li><a href='browse.php?p=".($page+1)."'>".($page+1)."</a></li>" : "<li><a href='browse.php?p=".($page-1)."'>".($page-1)."</a></li>"))
        .($page == $totalpages ? "<li><a class='disabled'>1</a></li>" : ($page != 1 ? "<li><a href='browse.php?p=".($page+1)."'>".($page+1)."</a></li>" : "<li><a href='browse.php?p=".($page+2)."'>".($page+2)."</a></li>"))
        .($page < $totalpages - 2 ? "<li class='page-dots'><span>...</span></li>" : "")
.($page < $totalpages - 2 ? "<li><a href='browse.php?p=".$totalpages."'>Last</a></li>" : "")
.($page < $totalpages - 1 ? "<li><a href='browse.php?p=".($page+1)."'><i class='fa fa-long-arrow-right'></i></a></li>" : "")."
    </ul>
</div>
";
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: where am i missing quotes?

Comment: Probably your mistake is `$page - 1`. Just use `($page - 1)`

Comment: Yes, I realise it might be the case, but I changed `.$page-1.` to `.($page-1).`, but still nothing

Comment: @DanielCheung look my answer. It gives the output.

Comment: really? Them it must be my server's problem since I did the same thing before?!